# TypeError: connectToMongo is not a function

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

**TypeError: connectToMongo is not a function**

*My code (Index.js)*

```
const connectToMongo = require('./db')
connectToMongo();
```

*My code (db.js)*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017"

const connectToMongo = ()=> {
    mongoose.connect(mongoURI,()=>{
        console.log("Connected to mongo successfully")
    })
}

module.export = connectToMongo;
```

**Anyone can help?**

Comment: is your typo `module.export`, which should be `module.exports`, exists in your code as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think this line

```
module.export = connectToMongo;
```

should be

```
module.exports = connectToMongo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the line of

```
module.export = connectToMongo;
```

to

```
module.exports = connectToMongo;
```

See: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/module-exports-how-to-export-in-node-js-and-javascript/